# How to preview image in tmux in iTerm2

Tags: tmux, images, iterm

[iTerm2 is able to display images within the terminal](http://iterm2.com/images.html). I'm using the [imgcat script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gnachman/iTerm2/master/tests/imgcat) and it works fine, but when I'm inside of tmux it does nothing. Is there a way to be able to preview images inline in tmux in iTerm2?

Comment: The version of `imgcat` you posted there DOES include some `tmux` workarounds; if it doesn't work, it may be a better idea to report it to https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues.

Answer (score 4):

It is working now.  Here is a screenshot using the current [`imgcat`](https://raw.github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/master/tests/imgcat) script along with

- iTerm 3.0.2
- tmux 2.2 (MacPorts)

on OSX *El Capitan* (10.11.5):

[image]

The developer is very active, and if it was not working last September there may be a related bug-report/issue number (there are many [open issues mentioning `imgcat`](https://github.com/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=imgcat)).

Comment: It's still not working for me. I updated imgcat and I'm on iTerm 2 (3.0.20160606-nightly). What version of tmux do you have? I'm on 2.1.

Comment: Doesn't work netiher in **screen** nor **tmux**.

Comment: @j4hangir have you checked your version of `screen` or `tmux` against the ones specified in this answer?

Comment: They don't match exactly of course, while I am using **tmux 2.3** and **iTerm 3.0.12**.